# Ember Data - Get parent value from child

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a widget model which has a shallow parent-child relationship. A given widget may be a "root" widget and not have any parent, or it may be a child widget which has a parent.

The ember data model looks like this:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name:         DS.attr('string'),
  parentWidget: DS.belongsTo('widget', { async: true, inverse: null }),
  isSubWidget:  DS.attr('boolean')
})
```

I'm trying to add a "displayName" property that will show the name for root widgets, or "parent name - child name" for child widgets

```
displayName: Ember.computed('name', 'parentWidget.name', 'isSubLob',  function() {
  if this.get('isSubWidget') {
    return "#{this.get('parentWidget.name')} - #{@get('name')}"
  }
  else {
    return "#{this.get('name')}"
  }
})
```

This is not working, however. The child lob's displayName always comes as

```
undefined - WidgetName
```

The json is being returned like so:

```
{
"widgets": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Widget Name",
    "is_sub_widget": true,
    "parent_widget_id": 1
  },
  ...
}
```

For the record, all the records are being returne by the json at the same time.

I feel like Ember *should* be asyncronously resolving the parent widget and the string should be updated as well, however it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I would say you have two issues:

1. You're not declaring an inverse to your `parentWidget` relationship, which means that Ember Data is guessing the inverse (and likely guessing wrong). You should change that declaration to look like this, just to be sure:

   ```
   parentWidget: DS.belongsTo('widget', { async: true, inverse: null }),
   ```

   I doubt that will fix your issue, but it's good practice.
2. You're not waiting for your promise to resolve before trying to use the name. You've specified the `parentWidget` relationship as being asynchronous, which means that `@get('parentWidget')` will *not* return a model. It's going to return a *promise* that will eventually resolve to your model. Normally this would be fine as the computed property would just recompute when the promise resolves, except that you're not watching the proper key.

   ```
   /* PS: Assuming that your comma was misplaced on this line */
   displayName: Ember.computed('name', 'parentWidget', function() {
                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
   ```

   As seen, you're only watching the `parentWidget` property. So if the `name` property on the `parentWidget` every updates, you won't be notified. Change that line to this and you should be good to go:

   ```
   displayName: Ember.computed('name', 'parentWidget.name', function() {
   ```

   Just keep in mind that the first few times through, `parentWidget.name` will still be `undefined`. It won't be the value you want until the promise resolves, which means the computed property could run several times before it does resolve.

Comment: No dice. I made some udpates with those changes, but I should clarify that all Widgets (around 300, unlikely to change) get loaded in the route, and this only tries to display when I try to select on from a dropdown later. I really feel like it should already have all the data it needs when it's displayed.

Comment: So to narrow this issue down, I'll need two pieces of information. First, does the computed property re-calculate when the promise resolves? (How many times does it run?) Second, if you place a breakpoint in the computed property the final time through, what does the model look like in the Ember Inspector? It it resolved? Does it have the `name` property?